# Div position is not fixed in different screen sizes

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my wordpress site. The problem is that I just made a div as a right side bar and placed some images onto it, which seems to work fine on my desktop but when I view it on my laptop it changes its position and goes downwards.

Here is my code for the div and image placements:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:188px; right:0px; border:0px solid #f00; width:25px;"><a href="#"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/delhi.jpg" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/noida.jpg" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/jaipur.jpg" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/chennai.jpg" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you give top right width in % rather thyan giving in pixels?

Comment: still not working dude.......i m unable to understand why??plzzz help me

Comment: @Mahindra Singh:try position :absolute, instead of position:fixed

Comment: but the problem is that i want fixed position is it possible with fixed???

Comment: @Mahindra Singh:Have you tried with absolute.absolute is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this approach helps, If I wanna use pure css, it would be somthing like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="box">Your anchor tags here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  right: 0px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue; /* just for developing, remove this later */
}

div.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f00; /* depends on you ;) */
  height: 100px; /* unfortunately you have to set height property :| */
}
```

A live example **[here](http://jsbin.com/eqikap/1/edit)** ;)

Comment: thnks evryone for helping me....i solved it now.......my isssue was that with bootstrap aal the images were auto resizing according to screen sizes as they are responsive design via bootsrap and the div which i placed wasnt changing according to that....